# Perform a random permutation on an array in C++

Tags: c++, c, random, permutation

I have one `int*` array and I want to perform a random permutation to this array. The function is similar with `randperm` in MATLAB. For example, I have an array `int* A=[0 1 1 0]` and if I call `randperm(A,sizeof A)` then one possible output would be  `A=[1 0 0 1]`

This is my function but there seems to be an error.  Can anyone determine what this error is?

```
void randperm(int* permMatrix,int n)
{
    int i, j, t;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        j = rand()%(n-i)+i;
        t = permMatrix[j];
        permMatrix[j] = permMatrix[i];
        permMatrix[i] = t;
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%d ",permMatrix[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error output shows such as A=[1 0 0 0] or A=[0 1 0 0]. I lost one bit equal 1

Comment: A variable of type `int *` is not a matrix, it can be an array though.

Comment: Are you sure `j` will be in the range of `0 to n-1`.

Comment: If this is not homework and you really need to implement it yourself, I'd suggest you use [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) instead.

Comment: @DanielFrey: It is not homework. I know random_shuffle function. But I want to edit my function. THanks

Comment: Dear all, Thank you for support. I editted it. Problem it is  j = rand()%(n-i)+i;-error

Comment: @user2938494 what was the fix?

Answer (score 6):

It's always best to use standard library facilities where they exist. In this case, the `<algorithm>` header has a function `std::random_shuffle()` that does exactly what you want:

```
#include <algorithm>

void randperm(int* matrix, int size)
{
    std::random_shuffle(matrix, matrix + size);
}
```

Comment: +1. I am still trying to figure out what the reason for the down-vote could be.

Comment: Probably the typo in the first word of the title

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of 'randperm' is correct but, may be sizeof(A) is not evaluated as 4. Please Check out value of 'n'.